# Function that will execute function depending on value. Functional programming

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I have two functions and they are executed depending of if statement. E.g.:

```
if(value) {
    doA()
} else {
    doB()
}
```

How to write function or object that will take the result and decide whether or not execute each function. I want to receive something like this:

```
exists(result).doA()
nothing(result).doB()
```

I want to learn some functional programming in JavaScrit so I woud appreciate any source from which I can learn FP in JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. You seem to have working code already, right (in the first snippet)? What do you mean by "*I want to receive something like this*"? Is that second snippet supposed to be a test suite, or a way to write the same thing as in your first snippet?

Comment: Are you asking for `(value ? doA : doB)()`?

Comment: Yes, something like (value ? doA : doB)()

Comment: I don't think you would gain anything by wrapping this trivial operator in a function then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write something like this, for example:

```
function exists(value) {
    return function (func) {
        if (value !== undefined) {
            return func(value);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

function nothing(value) {
    return function (func) {
        if (value === undefined) {
            return func();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

function doA(value) {
    console.log('doing A', value);
}

function doB() {
    console.log('doing B');
}

const foo = 'fool';
const bar = undefined;

exists(foo)(doA);
nothing(bar)(doB);
```

The *exists* function gets a value and returns another function. The function that is returned gets yet another function as argument, which is executed **if** the value passed is defined.

I've used “old school” anonymous functions in the example above to make it easier to understand. With ES6 arrow functions, you can write the *exists* and *nothing* functions more consisely, like this:

```
function exists(value) {
    return func => value !== undefined ? func(value) : null;
}

function nothing(value) {
    return func => value === undefined ? func(value) : null;
}
```

The “functional programming fun” really starts when you realize you can refactor these two functions by putting the common code in another function, that is then used to create the two functions, like this:

```
function executeWithCondition(predicate) {
    return value => func => predicate(value) ? func(value) : null;
}

const exists = executeWithCondition(value => value !== undefined);
const nothing = executeWithCondition(value => value === undefined);
```

This technique is called *currying*.

Usage of these functions is still the same:

```
exists(foo)(doA);
nothing(bar)(doB);
```

Here's the complete runnable code example:

```js
function executeWithCondition(predicate) {
    return value => func => predicate(value) ? func(value) : null;
}

const exists = executeWithCondition(value => value !== undefined);
const nothing = executeWithCondition(value => value === undefined);

function doA(value) {
    console.log('doing A', value);
}

function doB() {
    console.log('doing B');
}

const foo = 'fool';
const bar = undefined;

exists(foo)(doA);
nothing(bar)(doB);
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I wanted :)

Comment: nice demonstration of inventing an interface using some functional techniques – the resulting `exists` and `nothing` are mostly useless, but showing how to make something out of nothing is cool nevertheless !

Answer (score 1):

**continuation passing style**

here's an approach using [continuation passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style). you'll notice the implementation of `main` is not far off from your original encoding –
 once you finish wrapping your head around this, if you haven't already learned about [monads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)), you now know the best one (`cont`) ^_^

```js
// cont :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
const cont = x =>
  k => k (x)
  
// when :: (a -> boolean, a -> b, a -> b) -> a -> (a -> b) -> b
const when = (f,l,r) => x =>
  f (x) ? cont (l (x)) : cont (r (x))

// isOdd :: number -> boolean  
const isOdd = x =>
  x & 1 === 1
  
// doA :: number -> number    
const doA = x =>
  x + 1

// doB :: number -> number
const doB = x =>
  x * x

// main :: number -> void
const main = x =>
  cont (x) (when (isOdd, doA, doB)) (console.log)
  
main (3) // IO: 4,  doA (3) === 3 + 1
main (4) // IO: 16, doB (4) === 4 * 4
```

---

**data constructors**

here's another approach using simple data constructors `Left` and `Right` to represent a Fork [sum type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) – this results in a sort of [data-directed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-directed_programming) style where the control of `main` is determined by the input type

```js
// type Fork a = Left a | Right a

// Left a :: { fork :: (a -> b, _) -> b }
const Left = x =>
  ({ type: Left, fork: (f,_) => f (x) })

// Right a :: { fork :: (_, a -> b) -> b }  
const Right = x =>
  ({ type: Right, fork: (_,f) => f (x) })

// doA :: number -> number    
const doA = x =>
  x + 1

// doB :: number -> number
const doB = x =>
  x * x

// main :: Fork a -> a
const main = f =>
  // fork applies the left function (doA) to a Left
  // fork applies the right function (doB) to a Right
  f.fork (doA, doB)
  
console.log (main (Left (3)))  // => 4, doA (3) === 3 + 1
console.log (main (Right (3))) // => 9, doB (3) === 3 * 3
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to define the properties of an object with values set to functions

```js
const o = {
  exists: function(value) {
    return value ? this.doA() : this.doB()
  },
  doA: function(value) {
    console.log("A")
  },
  doB: function(value) {
    console.log("B")
  }
}

o.exists(void 0);
```