# What is the name of the wheel from FP, that I am trying to invent? (see the code)

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, fp-ts

The desired final typescript code is:

```
transform(input)(transformation1)(transformation2)(...
// input is any data, e.g. string or object
// transformationX should be a transforming function
```

I've wrote the code below so far, and I feel like I am inventing the wheel, i.e. something like this must be already implemented in FP, but I don't know how it is called. Can anyone tell which tool from https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/ can be used instead?

```
type Transformer = (transformation: Transformation) => Transformer
type Transformation = (input: object) => Transformer

const TranformerCreator = (input: object): Transformer
    => (transformation: Transformation): Transformer
        => transformation(input)

const transform: Transformation = (input: object) => {
    return TranformerCreator(input)
}

const transformation1: Transformation = (input: object) => {
    // do sometging with input

    return TranformerCreator(input)
}
```

Comment: I think you want compose/pipe, although that's a really weird way to use it. More normal would be something like `const transformString = pipe(trim, toUpperCase, add('foo')); const xformed = transformString(' bar  '); // BARfoo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the [continuation monad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)#Continuation_monad), where function application is used as the *bind* operation

```js
const cont = x =>
  k => k (x)
  
const add1 = x =>
  cont (x + 1)
  
const double = x =>
  cont (x * 2)
  
const square = x =>
  cont (x * x)
  
cont (2) (add1) (double) (square) (console.log)
// 36
// 2 -> add1 -> 3 -> double -> 6 -> square -> 36
```

Here's another encoding that may make it easier to see how it works. Instead of using function application to bind, explicit `bind` and `unit` functions are used. Note: "bind" here is unrelated to `Function.prototype.bind` and refers to the monad binary operation

```js
class Cont
{ constructor (run)
  { this.run = run
  }
  
  bind (f)
  { return new Cont (k => this.run (x => f (x) .run (k)))
  }
  
  static unit (x)
  { return new Cont (k => k (x))
  }
}

const add1 = x =>
  Cont.unit (x + 1)
  
const double = x =>
  Cont.unit (x * 2)
  
const square = x =>
  Cont.unit (x * x)
  
Cont.unit (2)
  .bind (add1)
  .bind (double)
  .bind (square)
  .run (console.log) // 36
```

Comment: Oh, finally. I asked on SO, on reddit and on github, and only you gave me the answer. Thanks!!!

Comment: Also, your solution is so elegant, unlike mine over-engineered one... Excellent

Comment: You're very welcome. You may also be interested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46918344/633183) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50913378/633183) ^_^

Comment: And probably [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46518885/633183) too

Comment: Lastly the grossly overloaded term "callback" is often conflated with the subject of continuations – [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46758784/633183) may help to guide you